# Is there a way to transform a function to accept a callable that is evaluated just before the function?

Tags: python, partial, functools

Suppose I have a list of strings:

```
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
```

And I want to compare all of them to a specific *lowercase* string using some function `foo`:

```
map(lambda name: foo('carol', str.lower(name)), names)
```

Is there a way to alter `foo` to accept a callable `bar` that evaluates just before foo is evaluated? So I can write something like this:

```
map(partial(foo, 'carol', str.lower), names)  # foo sees the name in lowercase
```

Comment: Have you tried `name_I_want in map(str.lower, names)`? I might be missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure if your post is confusing or I am just stupid...

Comment: Maybe my post is confusing. I have no idea what I'm asking for, really. :)

Comment: This is a very simplified example, what I want to do is to prepare a partial with functions that I can't edit (eg. imported from other modules) that fits a callable somewhere. That callable would process the value just before the function is called.

Comment: Your post is confusing, because you are demonstrating using some advanced and unnecessary python machinery (lambda, map, and partial) to accomplish a really simple thing.

Comment: @wim yeah. But I didn't want to make matters worse by using more complex code for the example. I'll be processing complex objects with phonetic distance functions instead of just strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what they made decorators for! Take a look at a decorator that lower cases all arguments pass to some function:

```
 def lower_args(func):
   @functools.wraps(func)
   def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
     l_args = map(str.lower, args)
     l_kwargs = {(name, str.lower(value)) for (name, value) in kwargs}

     return func(*l_args, **l_kwargs)
   return _wrapper
```

Used like this:

```
@lower_args
def foo(a, b, c):
  #and your code goes here
```

To do what you want, change the syntax slightly

```
def to_lower(mod_func):
  def deco(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      return func(*map(mod_func, args), {(k, mod_func(v)) for (k,v) in kwargs})
    return _wrapper
  return deco
```

Used like:

```
@to_lower(my_function)
def foo(a, b, c):
  #your code goes here
```

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way to do that is just to use a generator expression.  Where you use `names`, instead put:

```
(name.lower() for name in names)
```

It will be evaluated as the container is iterated ("lazily"), as you wanted.

Comment: This is the pythonic way to achieve composition of mapped functions.